# Unable to 'open' frameworks with cocoapods; Couldn't generate swift representation

Tags: swift, xcode, cocoapods

I've been using cocoapods in a few projects before, but never with `use_frameworks!` enabled. In my new app, I am perfectly able to **use** the frameworks through cocoapods, but I am not able to `CMD+click` any objects or functions from any of the frameworks. Xcode immediately says this:
Couldn't Generate Swift Representation
Error (from SourceKit):
"Could not load module: Google Maps"
[image: error]

The framework is functioning properly. **I can use it.** When searching for this, I only found answers for those with the problem that the framework wasn't found at all, and didn't work. Why is my framework working, but Xcode unable to show it to me?

My target's `Framework search path` is automatically set up to this (through Cocoapods):
[image: framework search path]